# How to calculate "confidence level" of results returned by MySQL FULLTEXT index query?

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search

Suppose you have a FULLTEXT index defined on a column in MySQL database table to allow for natural language searches. If you now run a query using MATCH() and AGAINST(), you can retrieve the "rank" of the search results, as described here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

For example:

```
mysql> SELECT id, body, MATCH (title,body) AGAINST
('Security implications of running MySQL as root'
IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score
FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST
('Security implications of running MySQL as root'
IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
+----+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
| id | body                                | score           |
+----+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
|  4 | 1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ... | 1.5219271183014 |
|  6 | When configured properly, MySQL ... | 1.3114095926285 |
+----+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The problem is that MATCH() returns some floating point number but no upper bound to it. I need to derive a "confidence factor" to each of the resulting rows as a percentage 0 to 100. For example, a confidence factor of 95% for a particular row would mean that it's very likely exactly what the user is searching for. Conversely, if the confidence factor is low, it'd be something like 10%.

Note that this is not a matter of selecting the larges score from MATCH() and setting that to 100. The row with the largest score may still be not at all what the user is searching for... So perhaps using MATCH() won't work but, could you please suggest some way to calculate such a "confidence factor"?

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: Not even google provides such value because it would be difficult to provide one. If you want something like this, then you have to forget fulltext search and need to embrace technologies like natural language processing and unsupervised machine learning. The price you pay will be the speed of "query".

Comment: It's true that Google does not provide such a value, but I still think that a reasonable and useful approximation can be derived. After all, the formula used by the index relies on word (stemmed/no stop words) occurrence frequencies across records, factoring in the length of the records, etc. So it's feasible to think that given a distribution of scores, if one of the records has by far the highest score, along with confirming that keyword do indeed occur frequently in that record, then the confidence of that particular record being the right one would be pretty high.

Comment: But you do not have any value to compare the score to, so you cannot express the score as a percentage.